# Why JavaScript null check doesn't working?

Tags: javascript, null

```
function readProperty(property)
{
  console.log(localStorage[property]) //Alerts “null”
  if(localStorage[property] == null)
  {
      console.log('Null chek')
      return false;
  }

  return localStorage[property];
}
```

log outputs "null", but 'if()' doesn't work. I try with ===, its not work too. Help please.

UPD: Thanks everyone this change helped me `if(localStorage[property] == 'null')`

Comment: Please produce code that we can run to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try with `if(!localStorage[property])`

Comment: To debug, you may try `console.log(typeof(localStorage[property]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The keys and the values stored with localStorage are always in the
> UTF-16 string format, which uses two bytes per character. As with
> objects, integer keys are automatically converted to strings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Try:

```
localStorage[property] === 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although: `console.log(localStorage[property])` may report `null`, the actual value is `undefined`.

So, in your `if` statement, if you test against `undefined`, you'll get a match.

Better yet though, just test for the existence or non existence of a value with:

```
 if(localStorage[property])...  // Tests for any "truthy" value
```

or

```
 if(!localStorage[property])...  // Tests for any "falsey" value
```

Comment: But `undefined == null`...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if you're trying to use the global [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or if it's a defined variable in your code.

If you're using the `localStorage` API, you should check if a key exists like this...

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem("my-item")) {
  console.log("item doesn't exist.");
}
```

The `.getItem()` method returns `null` when the key isn't defined so checking using `!` or `item !== null` work.

> `.getItem()` reference from MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem.

Answer (score -1):

you have to get item from localStorage using getItem() function like that

```
if(!localStorage.getItem(property) || localStorage.getItem(property)===null){
   // there is no item in localStorage with the property name 
}
```

Comment: Your two tests are redundant.